# Do I need to place any additional component(s) getween isolated grounds?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, isolation, flyback

Initially I bothered with this question regarding isolated flyback switch mode power supplies. However I'd be happy to investigate this question dipper.

So as the output of the power supply is isolated from its output - grounds can have widely different potentials which is OK until voltages become dangerous for the isolation strength. Besides the parasitic capacitance can lead to false signals transfer from part to part. If I'd have no additional information for the subject - I'd place a big (1M for example) resistor to let the extra charge flow slowly from the one end to another.

But I realise that this approach can have some drawbacks. I tried to Google for some reading but I did not use correct request nor there are no such articles in the first 10-20 results.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

No resistors are necessary, however it's usually necessary to add a capacitor from input to output to conduct switching noise and keep the output from flailing around with respect to the input and/or earth.

The capacitor has to be safety rated for the fully isolation requirements of the supply- so "Y" rated typically, but there may be other standards that are applicable. Remember it's in parallel with the isolation provided by the insulation in the transformer, PCB and opto (if you have one). Failure of any of those isolation barriers could result in an unsafe condition, so the standards are very high (high voltage rating compared to mains voltage and very, very low tolerable failure rate at temperature extremes).